# How to set class property default value from R.string.xxx

Tags: java, android

I have a singleton fragment class. I want to set a default value for the property `text` the text is from `R.string.testText`.

```
class TestFragment {
  private String text;
  public static TestFragment newInstance() {
        TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

So if i use:

```
    private String text =     getResources().getString(R.string.testText)
```

i will get error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment not attached to Activity
```

How to achieve this? thanks.

From a reason i need to change this `text` on some parts, and most of them has a default value. so i don't want to configure this value in `onCreateView`.

```
TestFragment f1 = TestFragment.newInstance();
f1.setText = "default"
```

And some are not default value.

```
TestFragment f2 = TestFragment.newInstance();
f2.setText = "222"
```

So i am asking if this is possible to set a default value from R file?

---

### Edit

I think i am wrong of understanding singleton pattern here. What am using is only static method here.

Comment: you should set the text in "onCreateView" or "onActivityCreated" of that fragment. Cause before that the fragment is not attached to any activity.

Comment: Create a singleton pattern that returns an instance from YourFragment, where YourFragment is NOT the singleton class. YorFragment extends Activity, of course.

Comment: @ThrashBean Y ou are right. I think i misunderstood singleton here. Here in my question is just a statice method. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add parameter Context in your new newInstance() method.
For example:

```
public static TestFragment newInstance(Context context) {
    if (fragment = null) {
        fragment = new TestFragment();
        text = context.getResources().getString(R.string.voice_search_label);
    }
    return fragment;
}
```